# getting error when triyng to extend modules in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to extend one module from another.

This is my code for the base module  called **add.js**.

```
var exports=module.exports={};
exports.tutorial=function()
{
    console.log("Guru99 Tutotial")
}
```

Extended module called **child.js**

```
var Tutor=require('./add.js');
exports.NodeTutorial=function()
{
    console.log("Node Tutorial")
    function pTutor()
    {
        var PTutor=Tutor
        PTutor.tutorial;
    }
}
```

in the **index.js** file I used below code to call the function

```
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    var localTutor=require('./child.js');
    localTutor.NodeTutorial();
    localTutor.NodeTutorial.pTutor();


    return res.send({error:true,message:'working'});
    //res.render('html');
})
```

But it shows following error;

```
TypeError: localTutor.NodeTutorial.pTutor is not a function
    at /var/www/html/nodejs/index.js:36:26
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at cors (/var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
    at /var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:224:17
    at originCallback (/var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:214:15)
    at /var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:13
    at optionsCallback (/var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:199:9)
    at corsMiddleware (/var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
```

how can I call a function inside the extended module in **index.js**?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know why you are nesting functions in your export where you can use a basic `module.exports` to achieve less chaining of functions.

below was how I was able to fix that except you really need `NodeTutorial` then you create a separate function for it.

`child.js`

```
var Tutor=require('./add.js');
module.exports = {
   pTutor: function () {
    var PTutor=Tutor
    PTutor.tutorial();
  }
}
```

or

```
var Tutor=require('./add.js');
exports.NodeTutorial = function () {
   return function pTutor () {
    var PTutor=Tutor
    PTutor.tutorial();
  }
}
```

`index.js`

```
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    const localTutor=require('./child.js');
    console.log(localTutor.pTutor());
    localTutor.pTutor();// use this or the higher order function
    localTutor.NodeTutorial()() // higher order function
    return res.send({error:true,message:'working'});
    res.render('html');
})
```

I got it to get the `Ptutor function` I will look into it if you really need `NodeTutorial`

Comment: is it possible to define a sub function inside the exported function?

Comment: Yea , that is making NodeTutorial as a Higher order function. then you will have to call pTutor as like this 'localTutor.NodeTutorial()()'

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer:Calling sub function from index.js

```
 child.js 

    var Tutor=require('./add.js');
    exports.NodeTutorial=function()
{
console.log("Node Tutorial");
return function pTutor()
{
var PTutor=Tutor
PTutor.tutorial();
}
}
    Index.js

    app.get('/',function(req,res) {
        var localTutor=require('./child.js');
        localTutor.NodeTutorial();
          localTutor.NodeTutorial()();
        return res.send({error:true,message:'working'});

    })
```

Comment: is there any way to create a sub function inside Nodetutorial () and call it in index.js?

Comment: ya it works.But is it possible to create a subfunction inside the exported function ?.in the following link  of node js tutorials for export modules they are defining a function inside the exported module and calling it in the index.js  **https://www.guru99.com/node-js-modules-create-publish.html**

Answer (score 0):

```js
Child.js

var Tutor=require('./add.js');
exports.NodeTutorial=function()
{
    return {newfunction: function(){ return Tutor.tutorial }};
}

Index.js


app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    var localTutor=require('./child.js');
    localTutor.NodeTutorial().newfunction()
    return res.send({error:true,message:'working'});

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Tutor=require('./Tutorial.js');
exports.NodeTutorial=function()
{
    console.log("Node Tutorial")
    this.pTutor = function() {
        var PTutor=Tutor
        PTutor.tutorial();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful if you could explain why your code would solve the problem. Either try to explain your steps or include parts of documentation with reference to the original.